# Apache Solr 5.3.1 basic authentication plugin causing issue

Tags: apache, authentication, solr

I am able to setup the basic authentication plugin using the blog below, for Apache Solr5.3.1, but nothing happens and I am still able to browse through my Solr admin console using firefox without password.

http://lucidworks.com/blog/2015/08/17/securing-solr-basic-auth-permission-rules/

(http)localhost:8501/solr/#/ instead of (http)localhost:8501/solr/admin/

Also when I place the following curl commands I get different results.

curl (http)localhost:8983/solr/admin/authentication

curl (http)localhost:8983/solr/#/authentication

I think I am missing the admin prefix in the console URL but found no way to change it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After lot of search & debug I finally found out the error.
The curl command was giving an error like message which I overlooked, something like curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 24.

It seems there was some problem in json parsing so I copied and pasted the exact json sample and modified it precisely while keeping the indentation as is and it worked.

```
curl --user solr:SolrRocks -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{  
"set-user": {"yepmeasolrupdateuser":"y08klasd"}
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/authentication
```

Also I found that !! characters in the password field were causing the curl command not to execute properly.

Thanks anyway.